# ASP.NET uploading a file to Amazon S3

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am in the process of uploading images to Amazon S3, however i keep getting the error **"Please specify either a Filename, provide a FileStream or provide a ContentBody to PUT an object into S3."**

Basically i am uploading an image from a fileupload control and then hitting the code below. It uploads locally fine, but not to Amazon. The Credentials are alright so it only errors when it comes to uplaoding.

Can anyone see why this is happening please?

```
protected void uploadImg(int prodId, int prodFormat)
    {
        if (imgPack.HasFile)
        {
            string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(imgPack.PostedFile.FileName);
            string filename = "img" + prodId + ".jpg";

            // Specify the upload directory
            string directory = Server.MapPath(@"\images\packshots\");

            if (fileExt == ".jpeg" || fileExt == ".jpg" || fileExt == ".png")
            {
                if (packUK.PostedFile.ContentLength < 716800)
                {
                    // Create a bitmap of the content of the fileUpload control in memory
                    Bitmap originalBMP = new Bitmap(packUK.FileContent);

                    // Calculate the new image dimensions
                    decimal origWidth = originalBMP.Width;
                    decimal origHeight = originalBMP.Height;
                    decimal sngRatio = origHeight / origWidth;
                    int newHeight = 354;  //hight in pixels
                    decimal newWidth_temp = newHeight / sngRatio;
                    int newWidth = Convert.ToInt16(newWidth_temp);

                    // Create a new bitmap which will hold the previous resized bitmap
                    Bitmap newBMP = new Bitmap(originalBMP, newWidth, newHeight);
                    // Create a graphic based on the new bitmap
                    Graphics oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBMP);

                    // Set the properties for the new graphic file
                    oGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                    oGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    // Draw the new graphic based on the resized bitmap
                    oGraphics.DrawImage(originalBMP, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

                    // Save the new graphic file to the server

                    string accessKey = "KEY HERE";
                    string secretKey = "KEY HERE";
                    AmazonS3 client;

                    using (client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey))
                    {
                        PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
                        request.BucketName="MyBucket";
                        request.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;
                        request.Key = "images/" + filename;
                        S3Response response = client.PutObject(request);
                    }

                    //newBMP.Save(directory + filename);

                    // Once finished with the bitmap objects, we deallocate them.
                    originalBMP.Dispose();
                    newBMP.Dispose();
                    oGraphics.Dispose();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                notifybar.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block;");
                notifybar.Attributes.Add("class", "failed");
                notifyText.Text = "Error Text Here";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            notifybar.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block;");
            notifybar.Attributes.Add("class", "failed");
            notifyText.Text = "Error Text Here";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to assign File or InputStream property of PutObjectRequest object. The code fragment should look like this one:

```
  using (client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey))
                    {

                         var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                         originalBMP.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                         stream.Position = 0;

                        PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
                        request.InputStream = stream;
                        request.BucketName="MyBucket";
                        request.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;
                        request.Key = "images/" + filename;
                        S3Response response = client.PutObject(request);
                    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much Alexandr! Worked a treat. Now jsut need to work out how to reduce the file size :D And hopefully this will help others.

Comment: below link might help to reduce image size without loosing its quality.
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/05/how-to-resize-size-image-without-losing.html